# Error converting data type varchar to numeric SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateValidicBiometricsData_Test]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @intErrorCode INT

BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * INTO #ValidicBiometricData_Stg FROM ValidicBiometricData_Stg


DELETE FROM #ValidicBiometricData_Stg WHERE (diastolic > 400 and systolic > 400 and resting_heartrate > 400) OR ActivityDate > GETDATE()

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



UPDATE STG SET STG.IsDuplicate = 1
FROM #ValidicBiometricData_Stg STG 
INNER JOIN ValidicBiometricData T ON 
STG.user_id = T.user_id AND STG.systolic=T.systolic AND STG.diastolic= T.diastolic AND 
STG.resting_heartrate=T.resting_heartrate AND STG.ActivityDate=T.ActivityDate
--AND DATEDIFF(d,T.ActivityDate,GETDATE()) <= 5

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



MERGE ValidicBiometricData AS T
USING #ValidicBiometricData_Stg AS S
ON T.ID = S.ID  AND T.USER_ID = S.USER_ID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
T.ActivityDateUTC    =     S.ActivityDateUTC, 
T.ActivityDate       =     S.ActivityDate, 
T.BLOOD_CALCIUM      =     S.BLOOD_CALCIUM, 
T.blood_chromium     =     S.blood_chromium, 
T.blood_folic_acid   =     S.blood_folic_acid,
T.blood_magnesium    =     S.blood_magnesium, 
T.blood_potassium    =     S.blood_potassium, 
T.blood_sodium       =     S.blood_sodium,
T.blood_vitamin_b12  =     S.blood_vitamin_b12, 
T.blood_zinc         =     S.blood_zinc, 
T.creatine_kinase    =     S.creatine_kinase, 
T.crp                =     S.crp, 
T.diastolic          =     S.diastolic, 
T.ferritin           =     S.ferritin, 
T.hdl                =     S.hdl, 
T.hscrp              =     S.hscrp, 
T.iL6                =     S.iL6, 
T.ldl                =     S.ldl, 
T.resting_heartrate  =     S.resting_heartrate, 
T.systolic           =     S.systolic, 
T.testosterone       =     S.testosterone, 
T.total_cholesterol  =     S.total_cholesterol, 
T.tsh                =     S.tsh, 
T.uric_acid          =     S.uric_acid, 
T.vitamin_d          =     S.vitamin_d, 
T.white_cell_count   =     S.white_cell_count, 
T.source             =     S.source, 
T.source_name        =     S.source_name, 
T.last_updated_UTC   =     S.last_updated_UTC, 
T.last_updated       =     S.last_updated,
T.UTC_OFFSET         =     S.UTC_OFFSET

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (
        ID,
        ActivityDateUTC,
        ActivityDate,
        BLOOD_CALCIUM,
        blood_chromium,
        blood_folic_acid,
        blood_magnesium, 
        blood_potassium,
        blood_sodium,
        blood_vitamin_b12,
        blood_zinc,
        creatine_kinase, 
        crp, diastolic, 
        ferritin,
        hdl,
        hscrp,
        iL6, 
        ldl, 
        resting_heartrate,
        systolic, 
        testosterone, 
        total_cholesterol,
        tsh, 
        uric_acid, 
        vitamin_d, 
        white_cell_count,
        source,
        source_name, 
        last_updated_UTC, 
        last_updated, 
        user_id,
        UTC_OFFSET,
        IsDuplicate
)
VALUES (
        S.ID,
        S.ActivityDateUTC, 
        S.ActivityDate,
        S.BLOOD_CALCIUM, 
        S.blood_chromium,
        S.blood_folic_acid, 
        S.blood_magnesium,
        S.blood_potassium,
        S.blood_sodium,
        S.blood_vitamin_b12, 
        S.blood_zinc, 
        S.creatine_kinase,
        S.crp, 
        S.diastolic, 
        S.ferritin, 
        S.hdl, 
        S.hscrp, 
        S.iL6, 
        S.ldl, 
        S.resting_heartrate, 
        S.systolic,
        S.testosterone,
        S.total_cholesterol,
        S.tsh,
        S.uric_acid,
        S.vitamin_d,
        S.white_cell_count, 
        S.source,
        S.source_name, 
        S.last_updated_UTC,
        S.last_updated, 
        S.user_id,
        S.UTC_OFFSET,
        S.IsDuplicate
);

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM


DELETE FROM #ValidicBiometricData_Stg WHERE IsDuplicate = 1

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



UPDATE #ValidicBiometricData_Stg SET ActivityDate = DATEADD(HOUR, -7 , ActivityDate )
WHERE source = 'withings'

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



ALTER TABLE #ValidicBiometricData_Stg 
ADD SBPGoalID INT, 
    SBPGoalDiaryID INT,
    DBPGoalID INT,
    DBPGoalDiaryID INT , 
    Token VARCHAR(30),
    ActivityDate1 DATETIME,
    Ntoken VARCHAR(30),
    Nactivitydate DATETIME

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM


UPDATE STG  SET STG.SBPGoalID = G.ID
FROM #ValidicBiometricData_Stg STG 
INNER JOIN HRA_EMP_ADMIN..User_Identities UI ON UI.UUID = 'VALIDIC_ID' AND STG.[User_ID] = UI.[User_ID]
INNER JOIN ActionPlanWSdb..UserProgramInfo UPI ON UI.[User_ID] = UPI.token
INNER JOIN  ActionPlanWSdb..Goals G ON UPI.ActionItemID = G.ActionItemID
WHERE G.GoalTemplateID = 25 

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



UPDATE STG  SET STG.SBPGoalDiaryID = G.ID
FROM #ValidicBiometricData_Stg STG 
INNER JOIN HRA_EMP_ADMIN..User_Identities UI ON UI.UUID = 'VALIDIC_ID' AND STG.[User_ID] = UI.[User_ID]
INNER JOIN ActionPlanWSdb..UserProgramInfo UPI ON UI.[User_ID] = UPI.token
INNER JOIN  ActionPlanWSdb..Goals G ON UPI.ActionItemID = G.ActionItemID
INNER JOIN  CoachingPortal_PROD..ValidicBiometricData VB on UI.uid = VB.[User_ID]
INNER JOIN ActionPlanWSdb..goalDiary GD ON GD.goalID = G.id AND GD.vid = VB.ID 
WHERE G.GoalTemplateID = 25 

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM




UPDATE STG  SET STG.DBPGoalID = G.ID
FROM #ValidicBiometricData_Stg STG 
INNER JOIN HRA_EMP_ADMIN..User_Identities UI ON UI.UUID = 'VALIDIC_ID' AND STG.[User_ID] = UI.[User_ID]
INNER JOIN ActionPlanWSdb..UserProgramInfo UPI ON UI.[User_ID] = UPI.token
INNER JOIN  ActionPlanWSdb..Goals G ON UPI.ActionItemID = G.ActionItemID
WHERE G.GoalTemplateID = 26 

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



UPDATE STG  SET STG.DBPGoalDiaryID = G.ID
FROM #ValidicBiometricData_Stg STG 
INNER JOIN HRA_EMP_ADMIN..User_Identities UI ON UI.UUID = 'VALIDIC_ID' AND STG.[User_ID] = UI.[User_ID]
INNER JOIN ActionPlanWSdb..UserProgramInfo UPI ON UI.[User_ID] = UPI.token
INNER JOIN  ActionPlanWSdb..Goals G ON UPI.ActionItemID = G.ActionItemID
INNER JOIN  CoachingPortal_PROD..ValidicBiometricData VB on UI.uid = VB.[User_ID]
INNER JOIN ActionPlanWSdb..goalDiary GD ON GD.goalID = G.id AND GD.vid = VB.ID 
WHERE G.GoalTemplateID = 26 

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



MERGE ActionPlanWSdb..goalDiary AS T 
USING #ValidicBiometricData_Stg AS S
ON T.ID = S.SBPGoalDiaryID 
WHEN MATCHED  THEN 
UPDATE SET 
T.goalid = S.SBPGoalID,
T.ActivityDate = S.ActivityDate,
T.ProgressGoal = S.systolic,
T.LastUpdated = GETDATE(),
T.Note = '',
T.VID= S.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.SBPGoalID IS NOT NULL THEN
INSERT (goalid, activitydate, progressGoal, note, vid, lastUpdated) 
VALUES (S.SBPGoalID, S.ActivityDate , S.systolic, '', S.ID, GETDATE() );

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



MERGE ActionPlanWSdb..goalDiary AS T 
USING #ValidicBiometricData_Stg AS S
ON T.ID = S.DBPGoalDiaryID 
WHEN MATCHED  THEN 
UPDATE SET 
T.goalid = S.DBPGoalID,
T.ActivityDate = S.ActivityDate,
T.ProgressGoal = S.diastolic,
T.LastUpdated = GETDATE(),
T.Note = '',
T.VID= S.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.DBPGoalID IS NOT NULL  THEN
INSERT (goalid, activitydate, progressGoal, note, vid , lastUpdated ) 
VALUES (S.DBPGoalID, S.ActivityDate , S.diastolic, '', S.ID , GETDATE() );


SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



UPDATE STG SET STG.Token = UI.User_ID
FROM #ValidicBiometricData_Stg STG 
INNER JOIN ActionPlanWSdb..goalDiary GD ON STG.ID = GD.id
INNER JOIN HRA_EMP_ADMIN..User_Identities UI ON STG.USER_ID = UI.UID

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM




UPDATE STG SET  STG.ActivityDate1= T.ActivityDate
FROM #ValidicBiometricData_Stg STG 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT u.token, max(gd.activityDate)  AS ActivityDate 
FROM  ActionPlanWSdb..UserProgramInfo U 
INNER JOIN  ActionPlanWSdb..Goals G ON U.actionitemID = G.ActionItemID
INNER JOIN  ActionPlanWSdb..goalDiary GD ON G.ID = GD.goalID AND GD.progressGoal IS NOT NULL AND GD.progressGoal <> 0
WHERE (G.GoalTemplateID = 25 AND (GD.progressGoal >= 160 OR GD.progressGoal <= 90)) OR 
      (G.GoalTemplateID = 26 AND (GD.progressGoal >= 100 OR GD.progressGoal <= 55)) 
GROUP BY U.token) AS T 
ON STG.TOKEN = T.TOKEN

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM




UPDATE STG SET  
STG.Ntoken = T.Token,
STG.NActivitydate= T.ActivityDate
FROM #ValidicBiometricData_Stg STG 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT token,isnull(max(date), max(CreatedDate)) AS activitydate from coachingportal_prod..Notifications
WHERE NotificationTypeID=7 and isread<>0 
GROUP BY token
) AS T
ON STG.Token = T.Token

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



MERGE coachingportal_prod..Notifications AS T
USING #ValidicBiometricData_Stg AS S 
ON S.TOKEN = T.TOKEN AND T.NotificationTypeID=7 AND T.isread=0 
AND (S.Ntoken IS NULL OR (S.Nactivitydate<S.Activitydate1 and S.Nactivitydate IS NOT NULL AND S.Ntoken IS NOT NULL))
AND S.user_id IS NOT NULL
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT 
(
        Token,
        NotificationTypeID,
        [Date],
        CreatedDate,
        LastUpdatedDate,
        isRead,
        UserID,
        ReadDate
)
VALUES 
(
        S.Token,
        7,
        S.ActivityDate1,
        GETDATE(),
        GETDATE(),
        0,
        0,
        NULL
);

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM




ALTER TABLE #ValidicBiometricData_Stg 
DROP COLUMN SBPGoalID , 
    SBPGoalDiaryID ,
    DBPGoalID ,
    DBPGoalDiaryID ,
    Token,
    ActivityDate1 ,
    Ntoken ,
    Nactivitydate 

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



--TRUNCATE TABLE ValidicBiometricData_Stg

--SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
--    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM


DROP TABLE #ValidicBiometricData_Stg

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

COMMIT TRAN


PROBLEM:
IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) BEGIN
PRINT 'Unexpected error occurred!'
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END

END
```

After all when I try to execute it, it is giving following error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure UpdateValidicBiometricsData_Test, Line 269
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: what is the data you are trying to convert.

Comment: MERGE ActionPlanWSdb..goalDiary AS T 
USING #ValidicBiometricData_Stg AS S
ON T.ID = S.DBPGoalDiaryID 
WHEN MATCHED  THEN 
UPDATE SET 
T.goalid = S.DBPGoalID,
T.ActivityDate = S.ActivityDate,
T.ProgressGoal = S.diastolic,
T.LastUpdated = GETDATE(),
T.Note = '',
T.VID= S.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.DBPGoalID IS NOT NULL  THEN
INSERT (goalid, activitydate, progressGoal, note, vid , lastUpdated ) 
VALUES (S.DBPGoalID, S.ActivityDate , S.diastolic, '', S.ID , GETDATE() );  All the data types are matched. I don't know what is happening inside this code

Comment: You need to reduce the problem down to just the statement that has the issue and find some representative data that causes the problem. Then **edit** your question to *just* contain that code and data rather than hundreds of lines of irrelevant code. But also try to put a bit more descriptive effort in also. See [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I thinkk here is the error

> you are inserting `''` value to vid (I guess of `integer` datatype) @line number 268

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.DBPGoalID IS NOT NULL  THEN
INSERT (goalid, activitydate, progressGoal, note, vid , lastUpdated ) 
VALUES (S.DBPGoalID, S.ActivityDate , S.diastolic,, S.ID , GETDATE() );
```

try to give null or empty value without single quotes'

or may be you of different column name having datatype as `integer` and you are inserting different value in that